# Google Content API for Shopping - Credentials work fine locally but not on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, google-api

I have taken the sample code from:

https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/developers-guide-dotnet

```
ContentForShoppingService service = 
    new ContentForShoppingService("ContentForShopping-Sample");
service.setUserCredentials(GoogleUsername, GooglePassword);

service.AccountId = GoogleAccountID;
```

I also used sample code from https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/contentforshopping_sample/contentforshoppingsample.cs?r=1067

I am using the Google Merchant email address/password and the Merchant ID for the above. I then locate one of our products using:

```
entry = service.Get("en", "gb", ProductID);
```

This works fine on my local server. I can then update the product by manipulating its properties, and then calling:

```
service.Update(entry);
```

Now, the problem is that when I run this on our live server it fails with:

```
Exception Details: 
    Google.GData.Client.InvalidCredentialsException: Invalid credentials
```

What are the reasons for the same credentials working on one PC and not on another?

Should I be using another method to submit my credentials? I found the alternative methods bewildering and I could find no other sample code that works specifically with `ContentForShoppingService`.

- The local PC is running Windows 7
- The problematic live server is running Windows Server 2008 R2

**Update**

I have taken the same code and put it inside a Windows Form Application. This application runs fine on all other machines I've tried it on, except for the live servers that we use. This would make me think that this is a security software/firewall issue of some kind...

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this was solved by going to:

https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en_GB

It appears that Google tries to learn which IP addresses are OK for your app. Despite me saying that the prevented addresses were fine, they were still being blocked.

[image]

The solution was to go to the live server, open a browser on there and then sign in to the Google account on there. Since you're signing in physically at that IP address, Google then knows that this address is not suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same issue, i solved it by enabling 2-step Verification. mentioned in the article  [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

To summarize this article, goto:

1. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744
2. enable 2 step verification
3. enter your information
4. enter your app name
5. generate your app password
6. replace in your password in your code

Good luck :)